# Pointing package.json to a specific React commit installs react-tools (not react)

Tags: javascript, npm, reactjs, package.json

When I add this line to my package.json:

```
"react": "git://github.com/facebook/react.git#08e4420019f74b7c93e64f59c443970359102530"
```

...and then run `npm install`, I find `node_modules/react-tools` installed when I expect to see `node_modules/react`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The problem is that the repository contains a [package.json](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/08e4420019f74b7c93e64f59c443970359102530/package.json) which names the project `react-tools`. So seems like depending on react via git urls is not supported. Perhaps you can use the version `0.14.0-alpha`?

Answer (score 1):

The code at `git://github.com/facebook/react.git` is not the same code that gets installed when you `npm install react`. Instead, the code [contains a series of build steps](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ede27d2e861cbeb89021cfd31ee84ef0909829b9/grunt/tasks/npm-react.js) that are used to build the npm package. As far as I know, there is not a way to easily use a specific SHA of the React repo as an npm package; you would need to clone the repo, build the project, and copy it somewhere you can `require` it.